# PDO Statement accepting INDEX [0], [1], [2], but not [fieldname1], [fieldname2], [fieldname3]

Tags: mysql, pdo

Beginner here trying out PDO/MySQL.  I am coding a simple SELECT * and displaying the results. The code below works fine to display the contents.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM names'; //fieldnames are id, name, email
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{echo  $row[0] . " | " . $row[1] . " | " . $row[2] . "<br/>";}
```

However, when I use the fieldname as the index instead of the number, I get a PHP notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: name

Codes below does not work.

```
{echo  $row['id'] . " | " . $row['name'] . " | " . $row['email'] . "<br/>";}
```

I have seen several tutorials where they have used fieldname as the index.  Can someone provide some further clarification on when/how the fieldname can be used instead of the number for the index?

Comment: You have [PDO::FETCH_NUM](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_NUM) set as a default mode. [Change it to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#options)

Comment: Tried:  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); but still did not work.  Also tried:

Comment: I am still curious though, what is "MySQL index error message"

Comment: Also tried:  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)), but did not work either.

Comment: MySQL index error message that appears on the web page when the script is run is:  "
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Data\test\index.php on line 38".  As an example for the ['name'] index.

Comment: var_dump($row):  array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Name"]=> string(9) "Henry Wik" ["Email"]=> string(18) "HenryWik@Telus.net" ["Phone"]=> string(12) "604-333-6666" } array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["Name"]=> string(10) "John Smith" ["Email"]=> string(19) "JohnSmith@telus.net" ["Phone"]=> string(12) "604-255-8888" } array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "3" ["Name"]=> string(8) "Jane Doe" ["Email"]=> string(17) "JaneDoe@Gmail.com" ["Phone"]=> string(12) "506-888-9999" } array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "4" ["Name"]=> string(9) "Mary Jane" ["Email"]=> string(20)...

Comment: `$row['name']` is not the same as `$row['Name']`.

Comment: That's why you should always explicitly name the fields you select, to prevent exactly this type of errors.

Comment: And where is mysql in this error message?

Comment: BRAVO!  Thank you so much! ...beginner's dumb luck!